# Android Bottom Navigation bar color changes to black after adding com.google.android.material

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

I just added `com.google.android.material` into my project , Bottom Navigation Bar color changes to Black. Screenshots are here

**Before**
[image]

**After** adding `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0`

[image]

Comment: Please post your xml code also

Comment: but you can change the background color of the navigation drawer with any color

Comment: The default style of the `BottomNavigationView` uses `colorSurface` as background color. Check your app theme.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I solved my issue and posted answer below.

Comment: Same here, and i have switched to custom theme colors, and it stays black

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue solved [reference](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started)

I changed `AppTheme` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`

```
Theme.MaterialComponents 
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

Answer (score -1):

The addition probably changed a certain definition of color or style. Try changing the color of the Bottom Navigation Bar to white (#FFFFFF)